# How to test connection to mysql server?

Tags: mysql, shell

I'm trying to figure out how to test if a connection is possible with a given set of user, pw, and db name info. I parse out the user_name, password and database_name from an environment file and then I would like to test if the connection is possible. If possible continue with the rest of the script and if not possible, exit and print an error message. I want to test the connection because I have another larger script that just runs everything but I can't tell where it fails if it does fail.

Comment: $conn = (SQL statement);
         if (!$conn){error output} else{do logic};

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make a no-op connection:

```
mysql -e '\q'
```

If I run this with a suitable `.my.cnf` file, `$?` is zero.  If I try to use a different user:

```
mysql -u root -e '\q'
```

then I get an error message (which can be redirected away with `2>/dev/null`) and `$?` is non-zero.

Note that this is a fairly limited test, compared to using a language with a SQL library and a connection that spans multiple commands.  E.g. one connection may succeed, but a later one may fail because of network conditions or a change to the user's conf file or to the server authentication.

Answer (score -2):

Im going to put htis as an answer so i can use formatting...

Do something similar to the following. I dont know what code you are using so this is a fairly generic example:

```
     $conn = (SQL statement); 
     if (!$conn)
         {error output} 
     else
         {do logic};
```

So if you have many statements and you do this kind of thing for each of them using a unique error output for each then you can easily tell which one is causing the problem by reading the output.

Comment: It is not shell, as I mentioned it is a generic example, php to be specific. You should still be able to check the conn variable for an illegal value each time you are using it. It just saves you running each one individually